# SDL2 error on startup

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I've recently started upgrading/updating from SDL1.2 to SDL2, which has been fairly easy so far, but my program now encounters an error on startup. I've localized the error to one function call that attempts to load a .bmp image. Any insight as to why my function doesn't work is greatly appreciated!

```
SDL_Texture *load_image(SDL_Renderer* renderer, std::string filename)
{
  SDL_Surface* loadedImage = NULL;
  SDL_Surface* optimizedImage = NULL;

  loadedImage = SDL_LoadBMP(filename.c_str());

  if(loadedImage != NULL)
  {
    //optimizedImage = SDL_DisplayFormat(loadedImage);
    optimizedImage->format = loadedImage->format;

    if(optimizedImage != NULL)
    {
        Uint32 colorkey = SDL_MapRGB(loadedImage->format, 255, 174, 201);

        SDL_SetColorKey(optimizedImage, SDL_TRUE, colorkey);
    }

    SDL_Texture* transformedImage = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer,optimizedImage);
    SDL_FreeSurface(loadedImage);
    return transformedImage;
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Could not load image: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    SDL_Texture* transformedImage = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer,loadedImage);
    SDL_FreeSurface(loadedImage);
    return transformedImage;
  }
}
```

Comment: How does the error look? Is there any message? If there is, what does it say?

Comment: Sorry, I should have included that. The error returned is: 
"Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 1.854 s
Press any key to continue."

Answer (score 1):

Your code has errors:

```
/* ... */
if(loadedImage != NULL)
{
    /* ... */
}
else
{
    /* ... */
    SDL_Texture* transformedImage = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer,loadedImage);
    /* ... */
}
/* ... */
```

The `else` block executes only when `loadedImage` is equal to `NULL`, but you call `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface` with it. That's probably not what you want.

---

```
/* ... */
SDL_Surface* optimizedImage = NULL;
/* ... */
if(loadedImage != NULL)
{
    //optimizedImage = SDL_DisplayFormat(loadedImage);
    optimizedImage->format = loadedImage->format;
    /* ... */
}
/* ... */
```

`optimizedImage` is equal to `NULL`, yet you access one of its members. That causes a segmentation fault, and raises a segmentation fault error!